# Fancybox link on all images in div

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, fancybox

I want to cover every image in the div #artikel with a fancybox link.
So basically every

```
<img src="image.png"></img>
```

should be converted into

```
<a href="image.png" class="fancybox" rel="artikel"><img src="image.png"></img></a>
```

Is there a way to achieve this effect with Javascript or a php function which is capable of it? (The content of this div is stored in a variable)

Comment: Notice that `<img>` tag should be auto-closed so this `<img src="image.png"></img>` should rather be `<img src="image.png" />` (and don't forget the `alt` attribute)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can change the php, that would be ideal. But if you must use javascript, you could use `wrap()`:

http://jsfiddle.net/ses7u/

```
$('#artikel img').each(function () {
    $(this).wrap($('<a/>', {
        href: $(this).attr('src'),
        class: "fancybox",
        rel: "artikel"
    }));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to add anchor tag to all images in your paGE,you can use javascript in your page

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function wrapAllImages() {
    $("img").wrap("<a href=\"image.png\" class=\"fancybox\" rel=\"artikel\"></a>");
}
</script>
```